# CANUSB SJA1000 Filtering

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, can

I am using a CANUSB adapter connected to my car attempting to read out only CAN messages with 11-bit identifier 0x1D6. I need to do hardware filtering because software filtering is too slow for my application.

The CANUSB protocol description (http://www.can232.com/docs/canusb_manual.pdf) explains how to set up filtering, and refers to the SJA1000 datasheet (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SJA1000.pdf) for a description on the hardware registers involved.

To set up the acceptance code I write "MFFFFF3AC\r" on the serial port. This should be equivalent to setting AC0=FF, AC1=FF, AC2=F3, AC3=AC on a SJA1000 controller. I came up with these values by shifting 1D6 to the left one bit, as the last bit is used for RTR, which I don't care about.

To set up the acceptance mask I write "mFFFFF001\r" on the serial port. From what I understand this should set the SJA1000 controller up to filter only using the 11-bit identifier specified above.

These are the IDs I get with this configuration:

```
0x0a8 0010101000
0x0aa 0010101010
0x0c0 0011000000
0x0c4 0011000100
0x0c8 0011001000
0x0d7 0011010111
0x2d5 1011010101
0x2fa 1011111010
0x31d 1100011101
0x328 1100101000
0x330 1100110000
0x349 1101001001
0x360 1101100000
0x364 1101100100
0x3b0 1110110000
0x3bd 1110111101
```

As you can see, no signs of 0x1d6. I do see them if I restart the device without entering filtering commands.

Can anybody familiar with SJA1000 filtering tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CANUSB device enables the SJA1000 into "dual-filter" mode so you want to be looking at figures 11 or 12 (depending on whether your are filtering 11-bit or 29-bit IDs) of the SJA1000 manual.

You can see this spec match up with the example given in the CANUSB manual for the M and m (code and mask) commands. For the mask, a bit of 1 means "don't care" and a bit of 0 means "care". If you don't want to utilize the "filter 1" portion (which compares not only the ID, but also the first byte of data in the message), set the code and mask bits corresponding to filter 1 to all 0s (so that it will only match an ID and data byte of 0, which won't happen).

Assuming you don't care about the RTR bit, you want to use: M00003AC0 and m00000010

Comment: Yes, this did it! Basically all I needed to do was left shift the desired ID 5 bits and add it to the acceptance code.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are the victim of a deeply, deeply flawed manual. I notice the "r" and "R" commands, which one would think are read commands, are listed as read commands but described as transmit. Furthermore, it states that 11-bit ids can be selected over the entire 11 bits, but not 29-bit ids. This is an obvious garbling of the function of the SJA1000 in basic mode, where only the 8 msbs of the 11-bit id field can be filtered. Even allowing for English as a second language, this is not a good sign.

You have not stated it, but I assume you're testing involved hooking up to an existing CANBus bus and reading what's on it. Furthermore, I suspect that the existing units all use the standard (non-extended) ID field with 11 bits, and you are using the "riii" command to read it.

The first thing you need to realize is that the manual makes no sense. Compare Fig.9 and Fig.10 in the NJA100 manuals. For 11-bid ids the id data is contained in ID 28-18,with mask registers 0 and 1 being used. For 29-bit ids, the 11 lsbs are ID10-0, and the mask registers corresponding are 3 and 4. It appears that the manual is using the R command, and then somehow pretending the id is formatted as if it were read using the r command, if that makes sense. The claim that using E0 instead of F0 to mask out the RTR bit is confirmation of this.

More confirmation comes from your id data. Your mask setup did not discriminate in the high bits, and I notice that all 10 id bits you show have acivity - that is, they are responding to don't-cares in the mask.

The one thing you've done right (I think) is left-shifting your mask bits, but not because of RTR considerations, but in order to left-justify the 11-bit id in the 12 left-most bits of the registers.

So I'd try M3ACFFFFF and m000FFFFF instead. If that doesn't work, try setting various combinations of bits in the AC0 and AC1 registers, and see ids you detect.